# Javascript infinite scroll with mouse drag

Tags: javascript, scroll, spinner, infinite-scroll, scrolltop

I have been implementing an infinite scroll with a spinner which appears at the bottom of the scrolling div when the scroll reaches bottom. That spinner has a height so the scrolling height of the container div increases when this spinner is displayed. In my scenario, first the user scrolls to the bottom, then the spinner with a specific height appears and the scrolling height increases and I'm using "scrollTop" to reach the bottom again. It all works fine with mouse wheel scrolling but when I tried to drag the scrollbar to the bottom with left mouse button after reaching the bottom the spinner appears as usual and and scrollTop works well but after that if i continue to drag down (even if I'm at the bottom), scrollbar jumps up. Thanks for your help.

I'm using onscroll callback to display the spinner and scroll with scrollTop:

```
  if (out.offsetHeight + out.scrollTop === out.scrollHeight) {
    loaderElement.className += " show";
    out.scrollTop += 100;
  }
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fm9cv3a3/